# What is the best method for key exchange?

Tags: encryption, .net, key-exchange

I have application working between server and client. All messages must be encrypted and decrypted. I use AES algorithm and I want method to hide the key.

I found Diffie-Hellman algorithm, but my problem is that I didn't find its source code. If the is another method for key exchange, please tell me.

Comment: three letters: [TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security)

Comment: Is there a reason why you are looking to implement this on your own versus using an existing solution?

Answer (score 5):

This is exactly what SSL/TLS are supposed to do. SSL/TLS uses asymmetric encryption just in the handshake to exchange the symmetric key that is used from that moment on to encrypt the communication. The key exchanged is called a masterkey and is only used for that session. The lifetime of a session can be configured.

The process is basically this when you use HTTPS, for example:

- Client establishes connection (three-way-handshake -> TCP handshake, after this the SSL/TLS handshake starts)
- Server sends certificate (which includes the public key)
- Client sends masterkey encrypted with the servers public key
- Masterkey is used for that session

This is of course just a broad description of the protocol and only applies when the client itself has no certificate which is the case in most scenarios.